# Help with definition on regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, definition

What does it mean $\frac{n-1}{2}K_{2}$?
In general which graph am I referring to if I write $l\times K_{2}$?
To add a little bit of contest, we are talking about undirected graph on n-1 vertices with adjacency matrix A, Denote the eigenvalues of A by $\lambda_{1}\geq \lambda_{2}\geq…\geq\lambda_{n-1}$.
Then “it is well-known” that $\lambda_{2}\leq-1$ if and only if $\mathcal{G}=K_{n-1}$ and $\lambda_{n-1}\geq-1 $ if and only if $\mathcal{G}=\frac{n-1}{2}K_{2}$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is the graph associated to that adjacency matrix A.

Comment: elcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) you can find some advises about how to ask a good question on this site

Comment: It really depends on the context, but often, $G+H$ denotes the disjoint union of $G$ and $H$, and multiplication by a positive integer scalar follows from it (for example, $2K_2$ denotes two disjoint edges. This notation is often used for describing graph families that exclude an induced subgraph. Here, if $n$ is odd, that might makes sense.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the paper or resource where it comes from ?

Comment: With the added context, I confirm that $\mathcal{G}=\frac{n-1}{2}K_{2}$  means $\frac{n-1}{2}$ disjoint $K_2$, so that the graph has $n-1$ vertices. (It is known that if a graph is $d$-regular and bipartite, then the smallest eigenvalue is $-d$).